# os.system() spaces in file path - 'C:\Program' is not recognized

Tags: python, excel, path, escaping, os.system

I'm trying to use the following code to convert a xlsb file into an xlsx:

```
import os

EXCELCNV_PATH = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCELCNV.EXE\""
FILE_PATH = "\"C:\\Users\\Tomas\\Desktop\\fix_excelcnv\\Book1"
cmd = "cmd /c " + EXCELCNV_PATH 
cmd = cmd + " " + FILE_PATH + ".xlsb\" " + FILE_PATH +".xlsx\""
print(cmd)

os.system(cmd)
```

and I'm getting this error message "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.". I'm using quotes around the path, which I thought would fix the issue but apparently not, it interessting to note that if I use only the first path with the same structure:

```
import os

EXCELCNV_PATH = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE\""
FILE_PATH = "\"C:\\Users\\Tomas\\Desktop\\fix_excelcnv\\Book1"
cmd = "cmd /c " + EXCELCNV_PATH 
#cmd = cmd + " " + FILE_PATH + ".xlsb\" " + FILE_PATH +".xlsx\""
print(cmd)

os.system(cmd)
```

excel is opened fine, so I don't think the problem is with the way the path is being written, but there is definitely something weird going on here, can someone understand how I could make this work?

I already tried using the process module instead of os.system, I tried using different types of quotes, I tried printing the cmd and running the command myself on the terminal (and it worked, which makes it seem even more strange that it isn't working now...). I've tried everything I could think of...

Comment: If you want to include literal double quotes in a string, it's cleaner to use single quotes as the outermost delimiter, so you don't have to escape the double quotes.  `'"Hello"'`

Comment: And it's also cleaner to use raw strings so you don't have to escape the backslashes.

Comment: You'll save yourself a lot of pain and suffering if you start using `pathlib` instead of trying to build up path strings by hand. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: I have tried the single quotes and it didn't make a difference for me, did you try that and it worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script generates the following command

```
cmd /c "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCELCNV.EXE" "C:\Users\Tomas\Desktop\fix_excelcnv\Book1.xlsb" "C:\Users\Tomas\Desktop\fix_excelcnv\Book1.xlsx"
```

which should give you the same error even when ran manually in the terminal (my guess is that you ran the command without the preceding `cmd /c` which is why you thought it worked).

The main problem lies in `cmd /c`, which is explained in the help provided by `cmd /?`:

```
If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
used to process quote (") characters:

1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
    on the command line are preserved:

    - no /S switch
    - exactly two quote characters
    - no special characters between the two quote characters,
      where special is one of: &<>()@^|
    - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
      two quote characters
    - the string between the two quote characters is the name
      of an executable file.

2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
    a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
    remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
    any text after the last quote character.
```

So you either remove `cmd /c` if you do not need it, or enclose your entire command (a sequence of 3 strings) into a string itself:

```
cmd /c ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCELCNV.EXE" "C:\Users\Tomas\Desktop\fix_excelcnv\Book1.xlsb" "C:\Users\Tomas\Desktop\fix_excelcnv\Book1.xlsx""
```

Don't worry if it looks weird, cmd will parse it correctly.

Also, your command doesn't seem to do what you claimed - "convert a xlsb file into an xlsx".
`excelcnv.exe` is not well documented but it seems you are missing a `-oice` flag, so perhaps try the following command instead:

```
cmd /c ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCELCNV.EXE" -oice "C:\Users\Tomas\Desktop\fix_excelcnv\Book1.xlsb" "C:\Users\Tomas\Desktop\fix_excelcnv\Book1.xlsx""
```

To build this command in Python it would be better to do what [@picobit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6030926/picobit) suggested by using `pathlib` especially for more complicated scripts, but here I'll provide a code similar to yours with the addition of `f` and `r` strings for better readability:

```py
import os

EXCELCNV_PATH = r'"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCELCNV.EXE"'
FILE_PATH_STEM = r'C:\Users\Tomas\Desktop\fix_excelcnv\Book1'
XLSB_FILE_PATH = f'"{FILE_PATH_STEM}.xlsb"'
XLSX_FILE_PATH = f'"{FILE_PATH_STEM}.xlsx"'
convert_cmd = f'{EXCELCNV_PATH} -oice {XLSB_FILE_PATH} {XLSX_FILE_PATH}'
cmd = f'cmd /c "{convert_cmd}"'
print(cmd)

os.system(cmd)
```